# How to buy books (Google Books) from my android application?

Tags: android, google-api, google-books

I'm developing an application that sells books, but these books are in Google Books Store. 
Is there a way to buy these books directly from my app?
If dont, how is the workaround to buy these books? I have to open the Google Book app? WebView?

Comment: looks like the api only gives you links to the online store... probably they want to handle all transactions, isn´t it?

Comment: What if i use in-app purchasing?

Comment: that is for "virtual products" you create for your application inside googleplay.

Comment: if you´re selling your own books and not those listed in google bookstore... could be!

Comment: How to make a book as a "virtual product" that i can sell via in-app purchasing?

Comment: the in app purchasing is just an string thing like "magical wand level 500", and once the user buys it, you allow it programatically. If you´ve got your books somewhere stored and the user buys the product, you can download or show the thing in the android application

Comment: Ohhh...i understood now. Thanks man. I will use in app purchase. :)